# Occurence of characters in common in two strings

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to use a *for* loop to calculate the number of times a character in one string occurs in another string.

e.g. if string1 = 'python' and string2 = 'boa constrictor' then it should calculate to 6 (2 t's, 3 o's, 1 n)

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Sorry, new to the forums...and Python. Yes sort of is a homework question.  Moreso teaching myself how to use the program by doing random problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty straightforward:

```
count = 0

for letter in set(string1):
  count += string2.count(letter)

print(count)
```

Comment: has a bug.  you should use set(string1).

Answer (score 0):

Use dict comprehension `{ch:string2.count(ch) for ch in string1 if ch in string2}`

I forgot you need a `for` loop and sum over all letters.

```
count = 0 
for ch in string1:
    if ch in string2:
        count += string2.count(ch)
```