# Count Common Characters in Strings Python

Tags: python, count, set, intersection

The output of this code continues to be 4. However, the output should be 3. The set intersection is present because I believe that is the key towards the answer. The reasoning for the answer being 4 instead of 3 comes from the number of 2 qs and 1 r that match s2 in s1.

```
s2 = "qsrqq"
s1 = "qqtrr"
counts1=0
counts2=0
letters= set.intersection(set(s1), set(s2))
for letter1 in set(s1):
    counts1 += s2.count(letter1)
for letter2 in set(s2):
    counts2 += s1.count(letter2)


counts = min(counts1, counts2)
print (counts)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you explain why 3 is the correct answer?

Comment: In s1 there are 2 qs and 1 r that match s2. I just want the answer to output this.

Comment: see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732515/occurence-of-characters-in-common-in-two-strings

Comment: I saw that and this is how I built my code. However, this does not give the answer I need.

Comment: @DrewBennett The answer should be 4. In `s1`, there is 1 `r` and 3 `q`s, while in `s2`, there are 2 `r`s and also 2 `q`s.

Comment: I think you could and should jam the logic into a function and run various combinations at it to verify whichever solution you choose is behaving acceptably.   eg s1{"abc"} s2{"def"} == 0 etc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to maintain a count of the number of characters in common, you should use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead of `set`.

```
from collections import Counter

s2 = 'qsrqq' 
s1 = 'qqtrr'

common_letters = Counter(s1) & Counter(s2)  # => {'q': 2, 'r': 1}
print(sum(common_letters.values()))         # => 3
```

Comment: getting ''int' object is not callable' this error at the last line

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that doesn't involve sets:

```
s2 = sorted("qsrqq")
s1 = sorted("qqtrr")

count = 0
while len(s1)>0 and len(s2)>0:
    if s1[0] == s2[0]:
        count += 1
        s1 = s1[1:]
        s2 = s2[1:]
    elif s1[0] < s2[0]:
        s1 = s1[1:]
    else:
        s2 = s2[1:]

print(count)
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. However, I like the simplicity of the top answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
s2 = "qsrqq"
s1 = "qqtrr"
counts1=0
counts2=0
letters= set.intersection(set(s1), set(s2))
print ("letters: "+str(letters) + " intersection count: "+str(len(letters)))
for letter1 in set(s1):
    print ("letter1 " + str(letter1))
    counts1 += 1
for letter2 in set(s2):
    print ("letter2 " + str(letter2) )
    counts2 += 1

print ("counts1 " + str(counts1) + " counts2 " + str(counts2) )
counts = min(counts1, counts2)
print (counts)
```

This results in;

```
[~]$ python /tmp/test.py
letters: set(
['q', 'r']) intersection count: 2
letter1 q
letter1 r
letter1 t
letter2 q
letter2 s
letter2 r
counts1 3 counts2 3
3
```

Analysis, 2 is the correct answer (q and r are the only letters common to both), 3 is the lower number of either sets unique values.

Comment: gosh I love print statements

Answer (score 2):

```
def commonCharacterCount(s1, s2):
    return sum( min(s1.count(char), s2.count(char)) for char in (set(s1) & set(s2)))
```

Comment: It would be better if you provided an explanation of your code, so that further readers would understand your code rather than copy-pasting it

Answer (score 1):

I replaced your original chunk of code

```
for letter1 in set(s1):
    counts1 += s2.count(letter1)
```

to:

```
for letter1 in set(s1):
    v = s2.count(letter1)
    print("{0}:{1}".format(letter1, v))
    counts1 += v
```

It outputs, it is the letter with occurrence counts:

```
r:1
q:3
t:0
```

It is correct, string `s2` is qsrqq and you check set(s1) which is set contains `r` and `q`
The counts are correct. Similarly, If check the 2nd for-loop, the outputs are:

```
q:3
r:1
s:1
```

therefore the minimum count is 4.

Answer (score 0):

Do a count for each letter, and take the minimum to find out how many of that letter are common to both strings. Then sum that up, and that's your answer.

```
for letter in letters:
    counts1 += s1.count(letter)
    counts2 += s2.count(letter)
    counts += min(counts1, counts2)
    counts1 = 0
    counts2 = 0
print(counts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it using no modules.

```
sum(1 for i in zip(sorted(list(s1)), sorted(list(s2))) if len(set(i)) < 2)

3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def commonCharacterCount(s1, s2):
    s=0
    for i in list(set(s1)):
        count1=0
        count2=0
        if i in s2:
            count1 = s1.count(i)
            count2=  s2.count(i)
            s=s+min(count1,count2)

    return(s)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing. Maybe you could add a short explanation to the code to help other readers and also explain why OP's code is wrong to help them improve.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, though very late...

```
def commonCharacterCount(s1, s2):
    
    count = 0
    
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        for j in range(len(s2)):
            if(s1[i]==s2[j]):
                count +=1
                s2 = s2.replace(s2[j],"",1)
                break
    return count
```