# how can i account for repeats in a checker function in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a clone of the board game Mastermind™ in Python. The way the game works is that is generates a random answer (in the game it's colors, in my clone it's integers). The player is then asked to guess answers, and gets feedback on the number of characters in their guess that are a match in the right place, and the number that are a match in the wrong place.

My code for the checker is as follows:

```
    #guess and anslist are list forms of every char in guess and answer, respectively
    
    for guessitem in guess:
        for ansitem in anslist:    

            if guessitem == ansitem and guess.index(ansitem) == anslist.index(guessitem):
                matched = True
                truematches += 1
                continue

            elif guessitem == ansitem:
                matched = True
                partmatches += 1
```

my problem is, i need to make it work for guesses that include repeats (i.e. "155"). example scenario:

```
    (answer: 519)
    (guess: 599)
```

output:

```
    matches somewhere in answer: 2
    matches in right place: 1
```

desired output:

```
    matches somewhere in answer: 0
    matches in right place: 2
```

Comment: In your example, considering the answer and guess both have a 5 & 9 in the same positions why aren't the matches in the right place: 2 and matches somewhere also 2 (i.e. count of matches regardless of position)?

Comment: by the way, just clarifying that "matches somewhere in answer" means matches that are **not** in the right place but are in present in the answer.

Comment: @HiddenToad--So  "matches somewhere in answer" is  (count of digits in common) minus (matches in right place).  It would seem better and simpler for the player to know (count of digits in common) and (count of digits in right place).

Comment: yes well thats not how the original game works. i'm attempting a clone of a board game.

Comment: @HiddenToad--guess I was thinking of another game (I believe hangman) where you are told the number of common letters and number of position matches.  Ah well,  provided code for one solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that given a guess and answer returns the counts you want.

**Code**

```
from collections import Counter

def count_matches(answer, guess):
    ' Computes desired counts as tuple '
    answer = str(answer)
    guess = str(guess)
    
    # Count matches in right place  through counting character by character comparison
    right_place = sum(1 for a, g in zip(answer, guess) if a == g)
    
    # Adapt answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269409/count-common-characters-in-strings-python
    # To count common digits
    common_digits = Counter(answer) & Counter(guess)       # Digits in both
    any_place = sum(common_digits.values())                # Count of digits in both answer and guess
    
    return right_place, any_place - right_place
```

**Test**

```
result = count_matches(519, 599)
print(f'matches somewhere in answer: {result[1]}')
print(f'matches in right place: {result[0]}')
```

**Output**

```
matches somewhere in answer: 0
matches in right place: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need nested loops, but just one loop over both guess and answer combined to check the number of right guesses in the right positions. Then you can check the remaining elements for inexact matches in a second step.

```py
def check_guess(answer, guess):
    answer, guess = str(answer), str(guess)
    
    # first get the exact matches out of the way:
    n_exact = 0
    answer_remain, guess_remain = [], []
    for ansitem, guessitem in zip(answer, guess):
        if ansitem == guessitem:
            n_exact += 1
        else:
            answer_remain.append(ansitem)
            guess_remain.append(guessitem)
    
    # now check the remaining items for matches in other positions
    n_inexact = 0
    for guessitem in guess_remain:
        if guessitem in answer_remain:
            n_inexact += 1
            answer_remain.remove(guessitem)
            
    return n_exact, n_inexact
                
check_guess(519, 599)
```

```
(2, 0)
```